# Setting mysqli.max_persistent > max allowed connections on server

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have LAMP server that is managed by another party that frequently chokes since the number of connections to MySQL server gets exhausted. According to phpinfo() mysqli.max_persistent = unlimited.

Shouldn't this value be less than the max number of connections allowed by the server? Seems like a reasonable solution to me.

Comment: Yes, but it's better to get rid of pconnect at all.